# Microphone transimts system sounds in 20.04

Tags: sound, headphones, microphone, 20.04, gigabyte

I have a headset that is connected to rear inputs. Speakers work good, but microphone captures every sound from system, for instance discord captures firefox and MS Teams sounds.

I've tried doing `sudo alsactl restore`. It lowered my sound a little, but it still comes through microphone.

I've also tried to do some work in pavucontrol. I have two devices listed as Playback:

- WEBRTC VoiceEngine
- teams-for-linux (only when I use MS Teams).

Recording devices are:

- Chrome input (don't know what it is)
- WEBRTC VoiceEngine

I have also disabled `Loopback` in AlsaMixer. `Rear mic` level is 100% with 0% boost.

Generally the microphone is working very well, but the main issue is that system sounds are also captured.

Motherboard is **Gigabyte B365M D3H**.